# react - instantly storing DataSet1 and DataSet2 to Redux Store where DataSet2 is derived from DataSet1

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

(sorry if similar question is asked, but I found ones on multiple action dispatches and re using the redux-batched-subscribe. That is not what I want)

I need to produce a dashboard similar to one shown below.

It uses three sources - DataSet1 (amounts added by users), DataSet2 and DataSet3.

DataSet2 and DataSet3 are derived from DataSet1 (i.e. certain calculations are done on DataSet1) using  utils/function.

[image]

Any time DataSet1 changes (user adds a new amount, edit or deletes it) DataSet2 and DataSet3 should be recalculated and dashboard should instantly update entirely.

I am trying to design it to avoid repetitive recalculations and circular re-renderings.

I am thinking of doing it using Redux-Thunk.

What is the React way of doing similar tasks ?

Thank you !

EDIT: 
Removed unneeded detail, added Reselect to tags

Comment: Derived state should not be stored. You can use memoization to avoid recalcs. You probably should look at reselect.

Comment: @zzzzBov thank you so much. You are a master to provide super short, but super useful comments. Reselect works great now - I implemented it on all selectors now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to React and Redux - it's awesome when you get the hang of it.

I presume you are using the `react-redux` package to handle the binding between React and Redux. This package provides a class called `Provider` which you wrap your application in. Provider does several things, but one of the big ones is that it subscribes to the store and triggers a re-render when the store changes.

As @zzzzBov mentioned, *derived values should not be added to the store*. For that we use selectors. In your case, that would mean DataSet1 lives in the store, and both DataSet2 and 
DataSet3 would be calculated by a selector. Just to make this clear, here is the flow of events when a user changes DataSet1:

1. User changes DataSet1, a function you have defined in `mapDispatchToProps()` dispatches an action on the store.
2. The reducers run, generating a new state object.
3. Any subscribers to the store are called and passed the new state object (in this case, Provider).
4. Provider triggers an efficient re-render of the components (by efficient I mean it checks to see if the piece of state they select in `mapStateToProps()` has changed).
5. Your components responsible for rendering DataSet2 and DataSet3 *select DataSet1 from the store, and derive DataSet2 and DataSet3 on the fly*, then pass them on to their respective components.

If you don't want the DataSet2 and DataSet3 components to re-render on every change to the store, use the library [`reselect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect). Reselect caches derived values, which in turn avoids spurious re-renders. When the state changes, Reselect checks to see if its input values have changed, if they have, it recomputes the output. Your components then select from Reselect instead of selecting directly from the state object.

Hopefully that helps. Good luck!